# MySQL: Is there a way to LEFT JOIN conditionally? (or similar?)

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm writing a query to get **ALL** of the products in the `products` table, and the sale price for each product **IF** a record exists for that item in the `specials` table.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM products P
IF (S.specials_date_available <= NOW() AND S.expires_date > NOW())
{ // The sale has started, but has not yet expired
    LEFT JOIN specials S
      ON P.products_id = S.products_id
}
```

I realise MySQL is not a programming language, but is there a way to create a query that results in the logical equivalent of the above?

The result set should look like:

```
 ID    Name         Price     Sale Price
 1     Widget A     10.00     (empty, because this item has no sale record)
 2     Widget B     20.00     15.45 (this item is currently on sale)
 3     Widget C     22.00     (empty - this item was on sale but the sale expired)
```

Comment: an alias is defined like this: collumn_name __AS__ alias

Comment: These are table aliases, not column aliases. Most (all?) DB engines have the AS keyword optional.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can move the condition to the `JOIN ON` part of the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM products P
LEFT JOIN specials S
     ON P.products_id = S.products_id AND
        S.specials_date_available <= NOW() AND
        S.expires_date > NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM products P
  LEFT JOIN specials S
    ON P.products_id = S.products_id AND S.specials_date_available <= NOW() AND S.expires_date > NOW()
```